# Setting invincibility frame for the player

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

In the game Im creating I only want the zombies to be able to hit the player 2 times every minute instead of taking away the hole health bar because it damages the player to fast.

```
public void checkCollision(){
    Rectangle r3 = player.getBounds();
    for(int i = 0; i < zombie.size(); i++){
        Zombie z = (Zombie) zombie.get(i);
        Rectangle r2 = z.getBounds();
        if(r3.intersects(r2)){
            if(!player.getInvincibility()){
                player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - 10);
                player.setInvincibility(true);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that checks the collision of the player and the zombie. I have made it so that the player only takes 10 in damage but then the player will never be able to get damaged again. I have tried to use an if statement to check if the player is invincible and the having a for loop inside the if statement that will make the player mortal when the int hits 30 000 but the zombie will still damage the player so fast that the hole health bar gats taken away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a method that is called every frame - call it updateTimers or whatever. This method should decrement the player's invincibilityTimer by a set amount. Then, if the player has non-zero invincibilityTimer, they are vulnerable to damage in checkCollission, which will also set the invincibilityTimer to a set number.

Answer (score 1):

Use an attack cooldown for your zombies.

In my game I have something like

```
public boolean isReadyToAttack() {
    boolean ret;
    long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - t0;
    timer += delta;
    if (timer > attackCooldown) {
        timer = 0;
        ret = true;
    } else {
        ret = false;
    }
    t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return ret;
}
```

Then you simply check this in your loop, if the zombie is not ready to attack he won't even if he is close (in fact it is better to check the cooldown before the collisions, it is less expensive)ø

Answer (score 0):

I like to make an alarm class to handle things like "wait 10 frames, then print 'Hello world!' to the console":

```
public class Alarm {
    //'timer' holds the frames left until the alarm goes off.
    int timer;
    //'is_started' is true if the alarm has ben set, false if not.
    boolean is_started;
    public Alarm() {
        timer = 0;
        is_started = false;
    }
    public void set(int frames) {
        //sets the alarm to go off after the number of frames specified.
        timer = frames;
        is_started = true;
    }
    public void tick() {
        //CALL THIS EVERY FRAME OR ELSE THE ALARM WILL NOT WORK! Decrements the timer by one if the alarm has started.
        if (is_started) {
            timer -= 1;
        }
    }
    public void cancel() {
        //Resets the frames until the alarm goes off to zero and turns is_started off
        timer = 0;
        is_started = false;
    }
    public boolean isGoingOff() {
        //Call this to check if the alarm is going off.
        if (timer == 0 && is_started == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can make an invincibility frame as such (assuming the player has an Alarm called invincibility_alarm and it is set to 30 frames when a zombie hits the player.):

```
//Pretend this is your gameloop:
while (true) {
    if (player.invincibility_alarm.isGoingOff()) {
        player.setInvincibility(false);
        player.invincibility_alarm.cancel();
    }
    player.invincibility_alarm.tick();
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```